# nodejs: if condition in pug

Tags: node.js, if-statement, pug

I am going bonkers over a simple if-condition in `pug`, which i am new to.

If i do this:

```
if(3 > 2)
 span(class="col s10") Some Label
```

it works fine and I can see the `Some Label`, but if i do:

```
if(mainObject.valOne > Object.keys(mainObject.someDict).length)
 span(class="col s10") Some Label
```

I cant see the `Some Label`. I have verified that the value in the `mainObject.valOne` is 5 and cant seem to understand how to see the length of the dict (which is expected to be less than 5).

Comment: try to store Object.keys(mainObject.someDict).length in const variable and then try to compare that

Comment: How does your `mainObject` look like? It seems to be working fine for me: https://codepen.io/zsoltime/pen/abmpMPP

Comment: Is `mainObject.valOne` the number 5 or a string 5?